# Group Policy: Enforce No Write Caching for Removable Drives

Tags: windows-server-2003, groups, removable-storage

We've run into a number of issues on our system where students are unplugging devices from workstations without safely removing them first. Whilst the results are often a very good learning experience (corrupted USB disks) it would be nice if it was possible to enforce the "no write cache" policy for removable drives through group policy.

A quick search through the available administrative templates shows nothing for this purpose though. Are there any solutions to this problem apart from locally configuring each machine?

Our domain controller is running Server 2003 R2 and the workstations all run XP SP3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution to your problem.

> *The policies for "Write caching and Safe Removal" have no effect on USB removable drives.*

Taken from : http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtrouble_e.html